# OTP Verification unknown keyword error in Twilio with Rails

Tags: android, ruby-on-rails, ruby, twilio, twilio-api

want to send android app hash along with the otp with the help of twillio but not getting proper tutorails in rails. i tried in this way

```
require 'twilio-ruby'
@client = Twilio::REST::Client.new("XXXXXXXXXXXXX", "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX")
verification = @client.verify.services('VXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX').verifications.create(app_hash: "HXXXXXXX", to: '+91XXXXXXXXX', channel: 'sms')
```

But getting againg and again error
**unknown keyword: app_hash**

I followed this tutorial https://www.twilio.com/docs/verify/api/verification

Comment: Please provide an example from the documentation that tells you to use `create(app_hash: ...)` because the example code on the linked page does not show that.

Comment: That is the problem. There is no example for same. In the docs all the parameters are just mentioned. Just like 'locale', 'channel_configuration', 'app_hash' e.t.c.

Answer (score 1):

Your app's hash string is the first **11** characters of the base64-encoded hash.
Try to pass 11 characters: Ex: `'He42w354ol9'`.

```
verification = @client.verify
  .services('VAXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX')
  .verifications
  .create(to: '+15017122661', channel:'sms', app_hash:'He42w354ol9')
```

**Source**: https://developers.google.com/identity/sms-retriever/verify#computing_your_apps_hash_string

Comment: I was trying to do it in same manner. But everytime I am receiving unknown keyword error. But when i don't use 'app_hash' key. It works perfectly fine.

Comment: Wha the version of gem? Use the last version.

Comment: any other option to do same functionality with another gem ?

Comment: I have this error: 

Twilio::REST::RestError ([HTTP 400] 60200 : Unable to create record
Invalid parameter: AppHashI 
https://www.twilio.com/docs/errors/60200.

When my app_hash dont have a value with 11 chars.

Answer (score -2):

The Twilio Ruby API excerpt goes like:

```
@client = Twilio::REST::Client.new(account_sid, auth_token)

verification = @client.verify
                      .services('VAXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX')
                      .verifications
                      .create(to: '+15017122661', channel: 'sms')
```

I don't see any app_hash parameter, where did you get that from? Try removing it and see what's going on.

Comment: In the docs 
https://www.twilio.com/docs/verify/api/verification?code-sample=code-start-a-verification-with-sms&code-language=Ruby&code-sdk-version=5.x
all the parameters are just mentioned. Just like 'locale', 'channel_configuration', 'app_hash', 'custom_code' e.t.c.

Comment: and in this github article, it is also mentioned https://github.com/TwilioDevEd/sms-verification-android-ruby/blob/master/sms_verify.rb

Comment: looks like its an initializer parameter...can you try without it and see what happens

Comment: This is not an answer and does not attempt to answer the question. It is a question itself and should be posted as a comment, not an answer.

Comment: Knushboo so were you trying to get it to work, or just trying to figure out why it wouldn’t work as you were trying in the first place?

Comment: I am trying to figure out that why it is not working. According to doc and github article this should work. And I also need to implement it is in my verification function as well.

Comment: Alright then, sorry about that, thought you just wanted to get it to work.